# Aggregate my SQL results based on time interval?

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I am trying to aggregate the row_date, starttime, and acdcalls so that I can get a sum of calls made in any given 15 minute period for that date.

Doesn't matter if they are in splits 100 thru 107.

Here is where I was able to get to so far:

[SQL Query1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNwYZ.png)

```
DECLARE @@searchdate date = '2022-2-17'
SELECT [row_date]  
  ,[starttime]  
  ,[split]  
  ,[acdcalls]     
FROM [CMS].[dbo].[hsplit]  
WHERE split IN (100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107)  
AND (acdcalls > 0)  
AND (row_date = @@searchdate)  
GROUP BY row_date, starttime, split, acdcalls  
ORDER BY row_date, starttime asc ;
```

Results

| row_date | starttime | split | acdcalls |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-2-17 | 630 | 104 | 1 |
| 2022-2-17 | 645 | 105 | 1 |
| 2022-2-17 | 700 | 105 | 1 |
| 2022-2-17 | 700 | 107 | 1 |
| 2022-2-17 | 715 | 102 | 1 |
| 2022-2-17 | 715 | 104 | 2 |
| 2022-2-17 | 730 | 100 | 2 |
| 2022-2-17 | 745 | 105 | 1 |
| 2022-2-17 | 745 | 107 | 1 |

Trying to get it to look like this:

| row_date | starttime | acdcalls |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-2-17 | 630 | 1 |
| 2022-2-17 | 645 | 1 |
| 2022-2-17 | 700 | 2 |
| 2022-2-17 | 715 | 3 |
| 2022-2-17 | 730 | 2 |
| 2022-2-17 | 745 | 2 |

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the splits don't matter, don't group by them and definitely don't group by the measure you want to aggregate on, just choose the aggregating function. I don't really know what `acdcalls` represent but if it's the number of calls via automated call distribution then you probably need a `SUM`:

```
DECLARE @searchdate date = '20220217'
SELECT [row_date]  
  ,[starttime]  
  ,SUM([acdcalls]) AS acdcalls
FROM [CMS].[dbo].[hsplit]  
WHERE split IN (100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107)  
AND (acdcalls > 0)  
AND (row_date = @searchdate)  
GROUP BY row_date, starttime
ORDER BY row_date, starttime asc ;
```

Comment: That did the job. Thank you MarcinJ !

Comment: I am now.   Thanks Dale.   :)